# Why is Ubuntu named Ubuntu?

Tags: community, history-of-ubuntu

I have long been interested in something. I know a lot of things about the history of Ubuntu, but I do not know about the name.

So, why is Ubuntu named "Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [About the Name, viewed with the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130223104643/https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/about-ubuntu/C/about-ubuntu-name.html):

> Ubuntu is a South African ethical ideology focusing on people's
>   allegiances and relations with each other. The word comes from the
>   Zulu and Xhosa languages. Ubuntu is seen as a traditional African
>   concept, is regarded as one of the founding principles of the new
>   republic of South Africa and is connected to the idea of an African
>   Renaissance.
>
> A rough translation of the principle of Ubuntu is "humanity towards
>   others". Another translation could be: "the belief in a universal bond
>   of sharing that connects all humanity".
>
> > "A person with ubuntu is open and available to others, affirming of
> >     others, does not feel threatened that others are able and good, for he
> >     or she has a proper self-assurance that comes from knowing that he or
> >     she belongs in a greater whole and is diminished when others are
> >     humiliated or diminished, when others are tortured or oppressed."
> >
> > — Archbishop Desmond Tutu
>
> As a platform based on Free software, the Ubuntu operating system brings the spirit of ubuntu to the
>   software world.

Comment: To clarify, this word *is indeed* in Zulu and Xhosa, but it isn't exclusive to those. It is a bantu/nguni word. Also, a lovely proverb in Zulu/Xhosa/bantu languages, pertaining to Ubuntu: *Umntu ngumntu ngabantu*. A person is a person with other people.

Answer (score 13):

> Ubuntu is a South African ethical ideology focusing on people's
>   allegiances and relations with each other. The word comes from the
>   Zulu and Xhosa languages. Ubuntu is seen as a traditional African
>   concept, is regarded as one of the founding principles of the new
>   republic of South Africa and is connected to the idea of an African
>   Renaissance.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/about-ubuntu/C/about-ubuntu-name.html

Also this is the release naming scheme: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Comment: Note that the linked "Source" 404's now. If you want to view it, you can use the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130223104643/https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/about-ubuntu/C/about-ubuntu-name.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Ubuntu in the Xhosa language means "I am because we are".

[image: Meaning of Ubuntu]