# Why is Unity named Unity?

Tags: unity, history-of-ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the philosophy behind Unity’s name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144117/what-is-the-philosophy-behind-unitys-name)

Something similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125321/why-is-ubuntu-named-ubuntu). Why is Unity named Unity? What's the idea behind the name?

Comment: @Anwar: I don't find any in search. Sorry. I think than is Askubuntu search problem.

Comment: No problem. I was merely indicating this was a possible duplicate. If you agree you can vote it to close.

Comment: Maybe they named it after the Soyuz :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Mark ShuttleWorth inaugural blog post about Unity](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/383), at the beginning Unity was designed to create an interface that would be usable on variety of machines (standard computers, netbooks, light versions)

A user could start his Ubuntu's experience on a tablet/netbook, then switch to his desktop and keep the same interface, **Unity** of the interfaces ;) .

Another reason may be the way that the applications are docked together. The runnable (launchers) and the running applications are merged in the same icons in the panel, that can be another way of **Unity** as well as the open Windows' toolbars being merged into the panel.

And last reason, as said on the [unity website](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/unity/),

> Unity is designed for mouse, touchpad, and keyboard use

again, no matter the way you can control your machine, you'll find **Unity** in the way it is managed.

Answer (score 9):

Unity refers to unified interface for various ubuntu devices, Eg. computers, tablets, mobile devices, tvs, etc.